# the number of images in Magento store

Tags: magento2, image

How many images I can upload for one product in my Magento store? I want to know the maximum number of images per one item. It's really important for my clothes store

Comment: Hi, you can upload up to 100 images for one single product. But if you are uploading in a  bulk then make sure upload_max_filesize limit will not exceeds.